# fatal error C1083: Cannot open file: atlconv.h: No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio, atl

I am using VS 2019 Professional.
File `atlconv.h` exists at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include

However, there're two folders at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\

`14.16.27023` and `14.28.29333`.

What paths does visual studio 2019 use when looking for `atlconv.h`?
Where can I find out about paths?

Comment: Visual Studio uses the latest tool (today 14.28.29333) in general. atlconv.h should be in all versions (it's an old file - on my machine, it's there in 14.16.27023). If it's not, there's a setup problem, you might want to try to repair your installation.

Comment: Select Project > Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories.  Click the dropdown arrow, Edit and the "Evaluated value" box shows the paths.